# Custom uri validation with php

Tags: php

I made one class called URL in URL.php

Now I have:

This is called to check is url true, for now just true.

```
public function isValid() {
    return $this->aa(ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), self::getUriData());
}
```

Here I am checking is passed path from uri inside array of arrays

```
public function aa($path, $uriData) {
    $path = explode('/', $path);
    if(!isset($uriData[$path[0]]) && $path[0]!==""){
        $uriData = false;
    }else if($path[0]==""){
        $uriData = true;
    }else{
        foreach ($path as $bit) {
            if(isset($uriData[$bit])) {
                $uriData = $uriData[$bit];
            }else if(ctype_alnum($bit)){
                 $bit = 'alphanumeric';
                 if(isset($uriData[$bit])) {
                    $uriData = $uriData[$bit];
                 }
            }else if(is_numeric($bit)){
                 $bit = 'numeric';
                 if(isset($uriData[$bit])) {
                    $uriData = $uriData[$bit];
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    return $uriData;
}
```

This is just getting arrays from some file written by hex code...

```
public static function getUriData() {
    //Hash is called from different file and there is no  problem with that
    $c = Hash::getHexData('valid-uri-dev');
    $a = json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $c), true);
    return $a;
}
```

**getUriData()** is returning this:

```
array(
    "users" => array(
        "" => true,
        "alphanumeric" => true,
        "numeric" => true,
        "messages" => true,
        "friends" => array(
            "all" => true,
            "same" => true
        )
    ),
    "admin-dev" => true
);
```

on **index.php** file I have:

```
$url = new URL;
if($url->isValid()) {
    var_dump($url->isValid());
}else echo 'This page does not exist!';
```

Now my problem is within **aa(),** look this:

if my url is:

***www.something.com*** - returns true

***www.something.com/32131132/*** - returns not true (idk null or something)

***www.something.com/dasdasadsa312312/*** - returns not true

***www.something.com/users/*** - returns true

***www.something.com/users/4h43h234/*** - returns true because I am checking in for loop first if it exist in array but then if not is it alphanumeric or so and if it is return true

But now in this case:

***www.something.com/users/friends/43243242ngjggj/*** - returns true as well but in that `$value` array there is not `'alphanumeric'` option but it still returns true

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Why not make use of [filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp) or [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) ?

Comment: I am not sure because I didn't use it before, but I thing that is checking is url valid like valid url, my validation is checking is some uri inside array to skip using htaceess and be able to add new uris from client page not from code if you understand what am I trying to accomplish?

Comment: Like array contains all pages that I added from client side, and some pages have sub pages like users/friends but users can have besides friends also some random alphanumeric values for maybe custom user_id, but that doesn't exist in friends. Only exists all or same pages, but its displaying as it exists there as well..